# Allow typing input into text field while selecting text

Tags: javascript, html

Given a block of text in a `div` and an `input` field:

[image]

I want to be able to select some text in the div (drag across it with my cursor):

[image]

Then click on the input field and enter some text while *"ome rand"* remains selected (unlike in the following image / JSFiddle):

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moa9xf2j/

My attempt at this so far has been to get the `startIndex` and `endIndex` of the selected text, then use `setSelectionRange` when the `input` field is clicked on. However, this didn't let me enter text in the field.

Comment: I'm not sure this is doable, not within the same frame anyway. I'd suggest putting the input in an iframe and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one active selection/cursor in any given frame.

In order to keep the old selection and still type in an input box, your selection and your input box need to be in different frames.

So do something like

> `main.html`

```
<html><body>
   <div>Some test</div>
   <iframe src="otherdoc.html"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

> `otherdoc.html`

```
<html><body>
   <input></input>
</body></html>
```

You can use `iframe`'s `srcdoc` attribute to avoid having a second document.

https://jsfiddle.net/p4ar85sg/